# Unable to return JSON Object, within Object in Android app

Tags: java, android, json

So I have an Android app I am working on that makes an API call to the server and returns JSON information. Now in my android app I can parse the JSON but only up until the first array. After that it says that category doesn't exist.

Here is the JSON response layout:

```
    [
  {
    "success": 0,
    "error": "string",
    "response": {
      "lastseen": 0,
      "mapstats": {
        "maps": [
          {
            "tier": 0,
            "modeid": 0,
            "modename": "string",
            "modecolor": "string",
            "bonus": 0,
            "name": "string",
            "rank": 0,
            "time": "string",
            "num_completed": 0
          }
        ],
        "highest_tier": 0,
        "num_beaten": 0,
        "percent_completion": 0
      },
      "tag_color": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "rank": 0,
      "avatar": "string",
      "tag": "string",
      "playtime": 0,
      "percent": 0
    }
  }
]
```

And here is my java class:

```
package com.horizonservers.horizon;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link MainFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link MainFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private static final Pattern delimeter = Pattern.compile(",\\s+");

    private TextView mResult;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment MainFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static MainFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        new PostDataTask().execute("https://www.horizonservers.net/api/v1/PlayerInfo");


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        mResult = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }


    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    class PostDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                return postData(params[0]);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                return "Network error !";
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                return "Data Invalid !";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                String NameInfo = jsonObject.getString("name");

                JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(NameInfo);

                for(int i = 0; i < jsonObject1.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonPart = new JSONObject();

                    //Log.i("response", jsonPart.getString("response"));
                    String newName = jsonPart.getString("name");
                    //mResult.setText(NameInfo);
                    mResult.setText(newName);
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                mResult.setText("Error!");
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);


            if (progressDialog != null) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }


        private String postData(String urlPath) throws IOException, JSONException {

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

            try {
                //Create data to send to server
                JSONObject dataToSend = new JSONObject();
                dataToSend.put("apikey", "UPj07lqWdetOWrk9M8Ya9UZzeIAizjr4sYQRKzkHFYm1KaQDopytCFq9HHCerwNy");
                dataToSend.put("steamid", "STEAM_0:1:90345825");
                dataToSend.put("maptype", "surf");

                //Initialize and config request, then connect to server.


   URL url = new URL(urlPath);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);  //enable output (body data)
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");// set header
            urlConnection.connect();

            //Write data into server
            OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
            bufferedWriter.write(dataToSend.toString());
            bufferedWriter.flush();

            //Read data response from server
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line).append("&");
            }
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
            if (bufferedWriter != null) {
                bufferedWriter.close();
            }
        }

        return result.toString();

    }
}
```

}

The specific part that prints the information to the screen is

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            String NameInfo = jsonObject.getString("name");

            JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(NameInfo);

            for(int i = 0; i < jsonObject1.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonPart = new JSONObject();

                //Log.i("response", jsonPart.getString("response"));
                String newName = jsonPart.getString("name");
                //mResult.setText(NameInfo);
                mResult.setText(newName);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            mResult.setText("Error!");
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

How can I parse these objects from the array/objects. I have already tried converting it to an array, but it becomes worse at that point. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean first array? Looks like your root element is an array not object. Did you try JSONArray(result) ?

Comment: yeah but that returns everything in the array. Then you have array's in an array. Which I don't know how to handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which data from your JSON response, you are trying to extract. But I think this example with Google Translate API will help you out.

JSON Response:

```
"data": {
    "translations": [
        {
            "translatedText": "Hallo Welt",
            "detectedSourceLanguage": "en"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I want to get the translatedText, "Hallo Welt", I do it like this:

```
public String parseJSONForTranslation(String jsonString) {
    try {
        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(jsonString).nextValue();
        return object.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("translations").
                getJSONObject(0).getString("translatedText");
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So as you can see, if you want to further extract information by going into the next "level" of your JSON response, you use either getJSONObject or getJSONArray (depending on if it's an array or not) until you reach the "level" where the data you want to extract is at. And you only use getString when you are at that last "level". Hopefully, this can help you out.

Comment: Okay I did what you said, that seems to be good; however, it only throws the JSONException and there is no error message as to why

Comment: Might not be able to help you right away, but feel free to update/post the code you tried so it's easy for somebody else or for me when I have the time to help you.

Comment: Fixed it, sorry just a bit on the slow side today thanks! You're awesome! I just was looking at the set up wrong! Your answer is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You can create JSON array when create JSON object fail

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
    // do something
}catch (JSONException e) {
    try{
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONArray(result);
    // do something
    }catch(JSONException e){
    //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't actually tested this myself but I think something like this should work.

The root element in your JSON is an array, so we will start there.

```
 public String parseJSONForTranslation(String json) throws JSONException {
  JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);

  // We have an array, so we can loop through each inner object.
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

     // Grab an object from the array so we can get the individual data
     JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

     // Variables that match the same key from your JSON
     int success = object.getInt("success");
     String error = object.getString("error");

     JSONObject response = object.getJSONObject("response");
     int lastSeen = response.getInt("lastseen");
     String tagColor = response.getString("tag_color");
     String name = response.getString("name");
     int rank = response.getInt("rank");
     String avatar = response.getString("avatar");
     String tag = response.getString("tag");
     int playTime = response.getInt("playtime");
     int percent = response.getInt("percent");

     JSONObject mapstats = response.getJSONObject("mapstats");
     int highestTier = mapstats.getInt("highest_tier");
     int numBeaten = mapstats.getInt("num_beaten");
     int percentCompletion = mapstats.getInt("percent_completion");

     JSONArray maps = mapstats.getJSONArray("maps");
     for (int i = 0; i < maps.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject map = maps.getJSONObject(i);
        int tier = map.getInt("tier");
        int modeId = map.getInt("modeid");
        String modeName = map.getString("mode_name");
        String modeColor = map.getString("mode_color");
        int bonus map.getInt("bonus");
        String name = map.getString("name");
        int rank = map.getInt("rank");
        String time = map.getString("time");
        int numCompleted = map.getInt("num_completed");
     }
  }
}
```