# Json object is not parsing in android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse a json in my android app, I receive json properly but when I try to parse it it does not seem to parse fine!

this is the json i am receiving :

```
   "GetAdResult": {
"Action": null,
"ActionValue": null,
"BgColor": "blue",
"CampId": 19,
"CampType": "cpm",
"ClickAddress": null,
"EndAnimation": null,
"ExplainText": "",
"ImageType": null,
"ImageUrlBanner": null,
"ImageUrlLargeBanner": null,
"ImageUrlMediumRectangle": null,
"ImageUrlFullBanner": null,
"ImageUrlLeaderBoard": null,
"LogoUrl": "",
"MainText": "",
"PackageName": "",
"ReplaceText": "",
"StartAnimation": null,
"VideoUrl": null,
"type":"ad"
"atag":null,
"message":"success",
"pixel":null,
"script":null,
"token":null
}
```

and this is how i am trying to parse it:

```
    public class JsonObjectSend
{
    private static final String TAG_action = "Action";
    private static final String TAG_acValue = "ActionValue";
    private static final String TAG_bg = "BgColor";
    private static final String TAG_id = "CampId";
    private static final String TAG_ctype = "CampType";
    private static final String TAG_adr = "ClickAddress";
    private static final String TAG_endAnim = "EndAnimation";
    private static final String TAG_expText = "ExplainText";
    private static final String TAG_imType = "ImageType";
    private static final String TAG_imgUBanner = "ImageUrlBanner";
    private static final String TAG_imgULBanner = "ImageUrlLargBanner";
    private static final String TAG_imgUMRect = "ImageUrlMediumRectange";
    private static final String TAG_imgUFBanner = "ImageUrlFullBanner";
    private static final String TAG_imgULeadBrd = "ImageUrlLeaderBoard";
    private static final String TAG_logoU = "LogoUrl";
    private static final String TAG_mainText = "MainText";
    private static final String TAG_packName = "PackageName";
    private static final String TAG_repText = "ReplaceText";
    private static final String TAG_startAnim = "StartAnimation";
    private static final String TAG_videoU = "VideoUrl";
    private static final String TAG_type = "type";
    private static final String TAG_atag = "atag";
    private static final String TAG_msg = "message";
    private static final String TAG_pix = "pixel";
    private static final String TAG_scrpt = "script";
    private static final String TAG_tkn = "token";

    public void sendobj()
    {
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject reqBody = new JSONObject();

        try {
            reqBody.put("DeviceId", "sdasda");
            reqBody.put("AppId", "ECC7BCE40126408386BCFCF8AB9187E7");
            reqBody.put("AdType", "text");
            reqBody.put("Location", "35.7209331,51.472983");
            reqBody.put("UserOperator", "Irancell");
            reqBody.put("Ip", "127.0.0.1");
            reqBody.put("NetworkType", "3G");
            reqBody.put("DeviceType", "Android");
            reqBody.put("DeviceBrand", "Samsung");
            reqBody.put("Width", "0");
            reqBody.put("Height", "0");
            reqBody.put("TestMode", "true");
            root.put("request", reqBody);

        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String tag_string_req = "Send_Object";

        JsonObjectRequest Req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.API_URL, root, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
            {
                try
                {
                    JSONObject jObj = response;
                    JSONObject GetAdResult = jObj.getJSONObject("GetAdResult");
                    Log.d("GetAdResult", GetAdResult.toString());
                    String action = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_action);
                    String actionvalue = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_acValue);
                    String bg = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_bg);
                    String campid = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_id);
                    String camptype = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_ctype);
                    String clickadr = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_adr);
                    String endanim = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_endAnim);
                    String exptext = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_expText);
                    String imgtype = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_imType);
                    String imgurlbanner = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_imgUBanner);
                    String imgurllargebanner = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_imgULBanner);
                    String imgurlmedrectangle = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_imgUMRect);
                    String imgurlfullbanner = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_imgUFBanner);
                    String imgurlleaderboard = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_imgULeadBrd);
                    String logourl = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_logoU);
                    String maintext = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_mainText);
                    String packagename = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_packName);
                    String replacetext = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_repText);
                    String startenim = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_startAnim);
                    String videourl = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_videoU);
                    String type = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_type);
                    String atag = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_atag);
                    String msg = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_msg);
                    String pixel = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_pix);
                    String script = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_scrpt);
                    String token = GetAdResult.getString(TAG_tkn);
                    Log.d("hg3uewygrhefkj","ufdjklc");
                    Log.d("action", action);
                    Log.d("actionvalue",actionvalue);
                    Log.d("Back",bg);
                    /*
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Log.d("Debug", errorMsg);
                    }*/
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("error", "Error");
                Log.i("onErrorResponse", error.toString());
                NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                if (error instanceof ServerError && response != null) {
                    try {
                        String res = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                        // Now you can use any deserializer to make sense of data
                        JSONObject jsonbody = new JSONObject(res);
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                        // Couldn't properly decode data to string
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e2) {
                        // returned data is not JSONObject?
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(Req, tag_string_req);
    }


}//class end
```

but when I try to Log.d the strings there is nothing in my logcat. how else am i suppose to do such thing?

Comment: First, don't capitalize adResult, it's an object, not a class.

Comment: and second? @JonathanJeffrey

Comment: I believe that you don't need to call jObj.getJSONObject() at all because you put all of the data at the uppermost level

Comment: @JonathanJeffreywould you plz look at my edited json object that i am receiving?

Comment: @Neshat your above JSON is not valid..!!

Comment: To be clear: only in the JsonObjectRequest onResponse method does Log.d not work? Is there an exception that is thrown or not?

Comment: B/c it might be simply that your logcat config is wrong, seeing that other Log statements, including `Log.d("hg3uewygrhefkj","ufdjklc")`, do not print.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to crate a POJO to represent this JSON object, and use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library to parse.

Comment: Good suggestion but OP is asking for solution not option.

Answer (score 1):

I posted an answer on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848383/unable-to-return-json-object-within-object-in-android-app/37848532#37848532) that might be able to help you out. 
So in your case, if you want to get "BgColor", you can do this:

```
public String parseJSONForTranslation(String jsonString) {
try {
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(jsonString).nextValue();
    return object.getJSONObject("GetAdResult").getString("BgColor");
}
catch (JSONException e) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your json response, there is no GetAdResult object which you are actually referring to. With the above code, "GetAdResult" should come in response and it should be root element.

Just remove  "GetAdResult" because it is not there as root element.
Try with ->   JSONObject GetAdResult = jObj.getJSONObject();

It will give you json object and then you can get all the string elements.

Comment: would you plz look at my edited question ? i edited json i should receive. can you tell me how to parse i now plz?

Comment: Now, there is no problem. Just add "{" and "}" around your json. GetAdResult should also be enclosed in curly brackets.              JSONObject GetAdResult = jObj.getJSONObject("GetAdResult"); This statement will work then.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
public String parseJSON(String jsonString) {
```

try {

```
 JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
 JSONObject adResultObj=object.optJSONObject("GetAdResult");
 String bgColor=adResiltObj.optString("BgColor");
 String campId=adResiltObj.optString("CampId");

} catch (Exception e) {

   return null;
}
```

In your code just replace your first line with my first line 
i.e replace below

JSONObject jObj = response;

with

JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);