# JSON parsing in Android with Volley Lib

Tags: android, json

I have the below json response.

```
[
{
    "id" : "001",
    "firstName" : "Theo",
    "lastName" : "Tziomakas",
    "role" : "CEO",
    "profileImageURL" : "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
},
{
    "teamName" : "iOS",
    "members" : [
        {
            "id" : "002",
            "firstName" : "Olly",
            "lastName" : "Berry",
            "role" : "iOS Team Lead",
            "profileImageURL" : "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png",
            "teamLead" : true
        },
        {
            "id" : "003",
            "firstName" : "James",
            "lastName" : "Frost",
            "role" : "iOS Developer",
            "profileImageURL" : "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
        }
       ]
   }
]
```

And want to read the teamName json object,and teamName json array.

This is what I do,

```
 public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d("Theo", response.toString());

            for(int i = 0;i<response.length();i++){

                try {
                    //[{"id":"001","firstName":"Mark","lastName":"Mason","role":"CEO","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},
                    // {"teamName":"iOS","members":[{"id":"002","firstName":"Olly","lastName":"Berry","role":"iOS Team Lead","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png","teamLead":true},{"id":"003","firstName":"James","lastName":"Frost","role":"iOS Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"004","firstName":"Liam","lastName":"Nichols","role":"iOS Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"005","firstName":"Chris","lastName":"Watson","role":"iOS Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"006","firstName":"Richard","lastName":"Turton","role":"iOS Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"007","firstName":"Matt","lastName":"Colliss","role":"iOS Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"008","firstName":"David","lastName":"Gibson","role":"iOS Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"009","firstName":"Tom","lastName":"Guy","role":"iOS Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"010","firstName":"Rich","lastName":"Hodgkins","role":"iOS Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"}]},{"teamName":"Android","members":[{"id":"011","firstName":"David","lastName":"Branton","role":"Android Team Lead","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png","teamLead":true},{"id":"012","firstName":"Dre","lastName":"Pilipczuk","role":"Android Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"013","firstName":"Ray","lastName":"Britton","role":"Android Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"014","firstName":"Charly","lastName":"Murillo","role":"Android Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"}]},{"teamName":"Web","members":[{"id":"015","firstName":"Ryan","lastName":"French","role":"Web Team Lead","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png","teamLead":true},{"id":"016","firstName":"James","lastName":"Ward","role":"Web Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"018","firstName":"Adam","lastName":"Smith","role":"Web Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"019","firstName":"Leonard","lastName":"Da Costa","role":"Web Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"}]},{"teamName":"Design","members":[{"id":"020","firstName":"Hannah","lastName":"Tempest","role":"Design Team Lead","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png","teamLead":true},{"id":"021","firstName":"Ellis","lastName":"Reed","role":"Designer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"022","firstName":"Pete","lastName":"Horsham","role":"Designer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"023","firstName":"Hemel","lastName":"Dave","role":"Designer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"024","firstName":"Hannah","lastName":"Corke","role":"Designer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"}]}]
                  JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    for(int j=0;j<jsonObject.length();j++){
                        JSONObject object = jsonObject.getJSONObject("teamName");
                        Log.v("Theod",object.toString());




                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

However, I get a complain stating that the "teamName" object doesn't exist.

Any ideas on that?

Thanks.

I can read the teamName for iOS:). But now I am confused with the member array. I have another loop

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d("Theo", response.toString());

            for(int i = 0;i<response.length();i++){

                try {
                    //[{"id":"001","firstName":"Mark","lastName":"Mason","role":"CEO","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},
                    // {"teamName":"iOS","members":[{"id":"002","firstName":"Olly","lastName":"Berry","role":"iOS Team Lead","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png","teamLead":true},{"id":"003","firstName":"James","lastName":"Frost","role":"iOS Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"004","firstName":"Liam","lastName":"Nichols","role":"iOS Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"005","firstName":"Chris","lastName":"Watson","role":"iOS Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"006","firstName":"Richard","lastName":"Turton","role":"iOS Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"007","firstName":"Matt","lastName":"Colliss","role":"iOS Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"008","firstName":"David","lastName":"Gibson","role":"iOS Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"009","firstName":"Tom","lastName":"Guy","role":"iOS Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"010","firstName":"Rich","lastName":"Hodgkins","role":"iOS Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"}]},{"teamName":"Android","members":[{"id":"011","firstName":"David","lastName":"Branton","role":"Android Team Lead","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png","teamLead":true},{"id":"012","firstName":"Dre","lastName":"Pilipczuk","role":"Android Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"013","firstName":"Ray","lastName":"Britton","role":"Android Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"014","firstName":"Charly","lastName":"Murillo","role":"Android Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"}]},{"teamName":"Web","members":[{"id":"015","firstName":"Ryan","lastName":"French","role":"Web Team Lead","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png","teamLead":true},{"id":"016","firstName":"James","lastName":"Ward","role":"Web Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"018","firstName":"Adam","lastName":"Smith","role":"Web Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"019","firstName":"Leonard","lastName":"Da Costa","role":"Web Developer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"}]},{"teamName":"Design","members":[{"id":"020","firstName":"Hannah","lastName":"Tempest","role":"Design Team Lead","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png","teamLead":true},{"id":"021","firstName":"Ellis","lastName":"Reed","role":"Designer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"022","firstName":"Pete","lastName":"Horsham","role":"Designer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"023","firstName":"Hemel","lastName":"Dave","role":"Designer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"},{"id":"024","firstName":"Hannah","lastName":"Corke","role":"Designer","profileImageURL":"http:\/\/developers.mub.lu\/resources\/profilePlaceholder.png"}]}]
                  JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(1);
                    for(int j=0;j<jsonObject.length();j++){
                         Model m = new Model();

                         m.setRole(jsonObject.getString("teamName"));


                         JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("members");


                         modelArrayList.add(m);
                         for(int k = 0;k<jsonArray.length();k++){

                             JSONObject teamMembers =            
          jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
          JSONObject teamMembers = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

           m.setFirstName(teamMembers.getString("fistName"));
                             m.setSecondName(teamMembers.getString("lastName"));

                             modelArrayList.add(m);
                         }
                         Log.v("Theod",jsonArray.toString());
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            // Update list by notifying the adapter of changes
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            //hidePD();
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);

}
```

but no data are displayed:(

Comment: this is a terrible data structure. Your root element is an array consisting of different types. I suggest you change it for something where the root element is an object, so you can access the different types by name.

Comment: I know that it is horrible,but this is what I was asked to do,and I am like what???

Comment: @njzk2 please read my updated kind of answer.

Comment: you are touching the same instance of `m`, whatever that is, and adding it as is.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848383/unable-to-return-json-object-within-object-in-android-app/37848532#37848532) which I believe can help you out.

```
public String parseJSON(String jsonString) {
try {
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(jsonString).nextValue();
    return object.getJSONObject(1).getString("teamName");
}
catch (JSONException e) {
    return null;
}
```

}